# drupal forum function hook to validate a list of words before posting

Tags: drupal, module, hook, forum

how can I implement a hook to validate the words that I'm posting ?
it seems that the forum lacks that feature: prohibited words
so I want to implement one even if I have to make my own module
I just need to know what function to hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the existing modules?

A quick search finds [Wordfilter](http://drupal.org/project/wordfilter) and [Phonetic Wordfilter](http://drupal.org/project/phonetic). I would suggest you try these out, even if they don't do exactly what you need their code will probably help point you in the right direction.

+++ EDIT +++

If you must do it when they post then use [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)

If you want to remove word automatically then run the 'presave' operation to alter the body before saving. Something along the lines of;

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL){
    if($op == 'presave' && $node->type == 'forum'){
        $node->body = preg_replace('#\b(word1|word2|word3)\b#i', '*removed*', $node->body);
    }
}
```

Or if you wanted to prevent the user from posting until they had removed any banned words then you use the 'validate' operation. Something like;

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL){
    if($op == 'validate' && $node->type == 'forum'){
        if(preg_match('#\b(word1|word2|word3)\b#i', $node->body)){
            form_set_error('body', 'You have used restricted words');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: they FILTER they don't prohibit you from submiting